# What is the best way to run a script remotely on Windows VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

For example, in Linux VM instances we can use `gcloud beta ssh` command to run commands remotely by downloading ssh keys using gcp credentials

Similarly, I am looking for running scripts on Windows VM instance remotely without doing RDP to an instance.

Can someone point to a solution for this problem?

Comment: The CLI `gcloud beta ssh` does use SSH keys. Google does not have a similar solution for Windows instances. Windows Server does include an SSH server that you can set up to support remote SSH sessions.

Comment: Azure has VM extensions. Does GCP have something similar?

Comment: Google does not have a similar solution for Windows instances.

Comment: `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port instance-1` can this command run scripts?

Comment: The serial port can run a limited set of commands. What do you mean by scripts - in the general sense, no you cannot run most types of scripts. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Windows workstation with PowerShell, you can connect to your Windows Server instances through a remote PowerShell session. This process is similar to connecting to a Linux instance using SSH. Please review "Connecting to Windows instances using the PowerShell terminal"

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#powershell

Comment: The link is now https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/connecting-powershell.  There were to many pending edits to update the answer.